# Best way to fix this inheritance structure?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm currently working on a Java project, I have 3 classes (I,H and O)that inherit from abstract class N. Where I and O  require a property described in class S and classes H and O require properties described in class P. Both properties P and S cannot be made with an interface. This causes the problem that if I were to implement a structure like this :
    N -> P
    N -> S
    and I -> S, O -> S
    and O -> P, H -> P
but this is impossible in java since it doesn't allow multiple inheritance.
A logical solution would be to make S inherit from P and P from N. But this causes the problem that I has properties from P which it doesn't need.

I'm looking for a clean way to implement this, thank you for your reading!

Comment: What do you mean by `->`? Do you mean "implements" or "is implemented by"?

Comment: I tend to read -> as "uses", is this correct? I don’t know what exactly you mean by "property". My immediate idea is to have interfaces UsesP and UsesS and have classes that use P and S implement them — or was that what you said was impossible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I relation to: "Both properties P and S cannot be made with an interface.".

If you need to get the field value, just define methods to be implemented, like:

```
public interface MyInterface{
 void getPropertyOne();
 void getPropertyTwo();
}
```

And remember that, since Java8 you could get default methods on Java interfaces, it could be useful if you need the same implementation for some of your subclasses, or you could get a similar behaviour using abstract classes.

Comment: Thanks this is indeed a decent solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to abstract the common properties in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to make your `P` and `S` classess singletons and use `Composition over Inheritance`. In other sense, you take the benefits from `P` and `S` by using them as `composite collaborators` of `I`, `O` and `H`.
Leave the N as abstract, but only if `N` provides common set of methods and fields.. In other words = `N` is a template for every class.

Here is how I see this:

```
class I extends N {
    private S s;

    public I(S s) {
        this.s = s; 
    }
}

class O extends N {
    private S s;
    private P p;

    public O(S s, P p) {
        this.s = s; 
        this.p = p;
    }
}

class H extends N {
    private P p;

    public H(P p) {
        this.p = p; 
    }
}

interface P {
    public String getProperty();
}
interface S  {
    public String getProperty();
}
```